# Summarizing data frame with multiple repeating grouping variable values

Tags: r

I have the following df:

```
df1<- structure(list(Type.of.Goal = c("Nutrition/Hydration Goal", "Nutrition/Hydration Goal", 
"Fitness Goal", "Fitness Goal", "Lifestyle Goal", "Fitness Goal", 
"Lifestyle Goal", "Fitness Goal", "Nutrition/Hydration Goal", 
"Nutrition/Hydration Goal", "Nutrition/Hydration Goal", "Lifestyle Goal", 
"Lifestyle Goal", "Lifestyle Goal", "Nutrition/Hydration Goal", 
"Lifestyle Goal", "Fitness Goal", "Fitness Goal", "Lifestyle Goal", 
"Lifestyle Goal", "Fitness Goal", "Lifestyle Goal", "Lifestyle Goal"
), progress_made = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), id = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "e", "e", "e", "e", "f", "f", 
"f", "g", "g", "g")), row.names = c(734L, 736L, 737L, 964L, 965L, 
966L, 1446L, 1447L, 1448L, 1449L, 1485L, 1486L, 1487L, 1553L, 
1554L, 1555L, 1556L, 1918L, 1919L, 1920L, 1952L, 1953L, 1954L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I am attempting to summarize the df to show which individuals (shown by the id column) 1) made progress on all the goals they set, 2) made progress on some goals, but not others, or 3) made no progress on any of the goals that they set.

If an individual made progress on a given goal, the `progress_made` = 1,
If an individual did not make progress on a goal, the `progress_made` = 0.

I was able to do this with no issues for individuals that only set one goal for each type available (Fitness, nutrition/hydration, and lifestyle), but for these individuals who, for example, set three goals that fall under only two goal types, I've been having problems.

Essentially I am looking for a final dataframe that has a stucture similar to:

```
df_results<- data.frame(id= c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"),
                     results= c("All goals saw progress", "No goals saw progress", 
                                 "Some goals saw progress, but not all", 
                                 "Some goals saw progress, but not all", 
                                 "Some goals saw progress, but not all", 
                                 "All goals saw progress", "All goals saw progress"))
```

It doesn't have to be this exact structure, but this is just the final information I need it to convey in one way or another.

My original strategy was to pivot the df wide so that `id` and `Type.of.Goal` are the columns and the `progress_made` values are the cell values. Following this I just used a combination of `rowSums` and `mutate` to assess what the value should be for each results category and then used `ifelse` to make a new column that summarizes the values to the text categories listed in `df_results`. However, this pivot method doesn't work when there are multiple goals set under a single type for any given individual.

Any ideas/help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R option:

```
aggregate(
  df1, progress_made ~ id, 
  FUN = \(x) {
    ifelse(
      all(x==1), 
      "All goals saw progress", 
      ifelse(
        any(x==1), 
        "Some goals saw progress, but not all",
        "No goals saw progress"
      )
    )
  } 
)

#   id                              results
# 1  a               All goals saw progress
# 2  b                No goals saw progress
# 3  c Some goals saw progress, but not all
# 4  d Some goals saw progress, but not all
# 5  e Some goals saw progress, but not all
# 6  f               All goals saw progress
# 7  g               All goals saw progress
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you tell me what the `\(x)` specifies? I have not seen that be used before.

Comment: It's short for `function(x)`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dplyr`. Summarise with `case_when`, `group_by` id.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 |> 
    summarise(results = case_when(all(progress_made ==1) ~ "All goals saw progress",
                                  all(progress_made ==0) ~ "No goals saw progress",
                                  .default = "Some goals saw progress, but not all"
                                  ),
              .by = id
              )
  id                              results
1  a               All goals saw progress
2  b                No goals saw progress
3  c Some goals saw progress, but not all
4  d Some goals saw progress, but not all
5  e Some goals saw progress, but not all
6  f               All goals saw progress
7  g               All goals saw progress
```